# coverting javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python

I have a yale smart alarm and come across the the below javascript that allows you to access the alarm to get the status and set it. I'm wanting to use this in my home assistant set to which uses python.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const setCookie = require('set-cookie-parser');

const urls = {
    login: 'https://www.yalehomesystem.co.uk/homeportal/api/login/check_login',
    getStatus: 'https://www.yalehomesystem.co.uk/homeportal/api/panel/get_panel_mode',
    setStatus: 'https://www.yalehomesystem.co.uk/homeportal/api/panel/set_panel_mode?area=1&mode=',
};

function getSessionCookie(username, password) {
    let sessionCookie = null;

    return fetch(urls.login, { 
        method: 'POST', 
        body: `id=${encodeURIComponent(username)}&password=${password}&rememberme=on&notify_id=&reg_id=Name`,
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
          'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        },
    })
    .then((res) => {
        sessionCookie = res.headers._headers['set-cookie'];

        return res.json();
    }).then(json => {
        if (json.result === '0') {
            return Promise.reject('Incorrect account details');
        }
        else {
            return sessionCookie[0];
        }
    })
}

function getStatus(sessionCookie) {
    return fetch(urls.getStatus, { 
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
          'Cookie': sessionCookie,
        },
    }).then(res => res.text()).then(textResponse => {
        // When initially writing this code I found if cookie payload 
        // was invalid I got this text response so I added this code to
        // handle this, shouldn't happen but good to have an error message
        // for this use case
        if (textResponse === 'Disallowed Key Characters.') {
            return Promise.reject('Invalid request');
        }
        else {
            try {
                // Hopefully if we got to this point we can parse the json
                const json = JSON.parse(textResponse);

                if (json.result === '0') {
                    return Promise.reject('Unable to get status');
                }
                else {
                    return json;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                // If you get this error message I likely have not handled 
                // a error state that I wasnt aware of
                return Promise.reject('Unable to parse response');
            }
        }
    });
}

function setStatus (sessionCookie, mode) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!sessionCookie || sessionCookie.length === 0) {
            reject('Please call getSessionCookie to get your session cookie first');
        }

        if (mode !== 'arm' && mode !== 'home' && mode !== 'disarm') {
            reject('Invalid mode passed to setStatus');
        }

        resolve(fetch(`${urls.setStatus}${mode}`, { 
            method: 'POST', 
            headers: {
              'Cookie': sessionCookie,
            },
        }));
    });
}

module.exports = {
    getSessionCookie,
    getStatus,
    setStatus,
}
```

i'm every new to coding but was able to piece the below together to return the current status of my alarm. the problem is I'm unable to get it to work. based on the above code could someone please tell me what I'm missing, or if I'm going down the wrong rabbit hole....

```
import requests
import webbrowser

url = “https://www.yalehomesystem.co.uk/homeportal/api/login/check_login”

payload = {‘username’: ‘email@domaim.com’, ‘password’: ‘mypass’}

with requests.session() as s:
# fetch the login page
s.get(url, data=payload)

url1='https://www.yalehomesystem.co.uk/homeportal/api/panel/get_panel_mode'

# post to the login form
r = s.post(url1, data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

To add more contexts I'm getting the following error

{"result":"0","message":"system.permission_denied","code":"999"}

Comment: What's the error message, or the unexpected behavior? "It doesn't work" is not useful.

Comment: One thing wrong with your code is that the lines that should be a part of the `with` block are not indented

Comment: Also, you're never POSTing to the login page, so you never log in.  The "post to the login form" comment is incorrect.  You're posting to the `get_panel_mode` page.

Comment: My understanding is I use the first url to log in and grab the cookie and then use It To get the status.